# Transition on an element works in Chrome but does not work in Firefox

Tags: css

So i was doing a tutorial from webdev, and i hit a stump. The transition animation on an element works fine on chrome but does not work on firefox. Then element starts out with `transform: translateX(110%);` and a `transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;`, and then we translate it to 0 so it looks like it slides off the screen. Funny thing is if you inspect the element and toggle the transform then it animates properly. Anyone got idea whats going on.

[CodePenExample](https://codepen.io/alexkourganov/pen/oNpjrZQ?editors=1111)

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/live-toast-notification-library)

Comment: First of all, only html inside the body tag goes into the html, your javascript is invalid, so i'd fix all your errors first before claiming a certain browser has issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is from browser engines between [Firefox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla) and [Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine)) and many more, especially in terms of DOM manipulation.

To overcome this kind of situation, I personally use a trick with `setTimeout` to put the action into [the callstack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Call_stack) which will be executed when all other tasks done.

In your case, I added it to make sure the toast appended first and then I'll do the animation

```
setTimeout(() => {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
     this.#toastElem.classList.add("show")
  })
}, 50)
```

Comment: Using either a timeout **or** the raf will do.

Comment: I'm just curious, which raf you meant? @connexo

Comment: requestAnimationFrame = raf

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
-webkit-transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
```

This will work for mozila firefox.

Comment: The vendor prefix is not necessary since Firefox 16, see https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_transition. So clearly that is not the issue here.